# django-registration view customization

Tags: django, django-forms, django-urls, django-registration

I'm using `django-registration` (see: https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration ) on one of my projects. The standard setup for the django-registration is to add a the code below in the `urls.py` file

```
(r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls'))
```

and also customize the templates in a folder called `registration`.

The code above is creating links to the registration, login and password recovery which is fine. But in my project there are some other functions I usually add to my views so if I just add the `include('registration.urls')` it appears that I have no way of customizing the views containing those django-registration forms.

Is there a way to call the forms used by  the `django-registration`in a view so I can add a few more things on those views ?

Comment: If I am getting u right u want to customize the registration form, if so then just copy the code from the repository in your app and make the necessary changes in the module.......If it was not upto mark than plz do reply.

Comment: I don't need to customize the forms, I just need to bring them in a view I want to create. For example when I show the registration form I wand also to add a custom function (in the same view) that will do a certain type of tracking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The registration form is provided by the registration backend. Check out `registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend`.

There's a method `get_form_class(request)` that returns the `registration.forms.RegistrationForm` class. All you have to do is create a new backend, inherit from `DefaultBackend` and override the `get_form_class()` method to return a new form class.

You can pretty much do anything by providing a custom backend, except changing the base behavior of the registration app. If you need to radically customize the views in a manner that providing a custm backend doesn't make the cut, then just create a `authn` or `users` app and import any bits from django-registration you find useful. You can, say, keep the default models and managers within the `registration` app namespace, but hook up a custom backend to your own internals in a new app.

Comment: If I'm not asking too much could you please provide a real example. Let's say if I want to bring the registration from, or the login form in a view I want to create how exactly I'm I going to do that? I don't want to customize the form itself I just want to add some functions around it so when my view is called my functions will show up along with the registration form or other authentication forms. Thank you!

Comment: Of course I can. Here, I've dropped a gist (https://gist.github.com/819235) where I merged the registration backend into a class-based view (a more extreme example). Most of what's generic for each registration process is defined on the `RegistrationProfile` manager. You'll notice that I'm using the model and manager provided in django-registration, but I'm providing my own behavior. The API for the backends is fairly flexible, so you can achieve most things with intercepting the signals and providing your `class MyBackend(DefaultBackend):`, but this is just to show what else is possible.